# How to know if an application is using system proxy and tor network?

Tags: networking, proxy, utorrent, tor, socks-proxy

I'm using socks proxy to connect to Tor network by Vidalia (relay) and it's working fine.

I have set the system proxy via `Control panel » Internet options` to use socks proxy. So no need to add extensions in Chrome. Tor is working fine in Chrome even without addons like *Proxy switchy*.

**Q1:** Should I configure *Internet Download Manager*, *uTorrent* etc. to "use no proxy" or "use system proxy"?  I always want all programs to connect through tor network.

**Q2:** Even If I choose to use "no proxy" in uTorrent, then does uTorrent connect to internet directly or via system proxy?

I believe uTorrent will connect through proxy (tor network) even if I set to "no proxy" because my Internet connection itself is connecting through system proxy. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know, but there's no point in using uTorrent with Tor. You will see veeery low speed...

Comment: Could you post your routing table?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae what's routing table? where should I look for?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: win 7 ultimate 64-bit

Comment: Open a terminal, and issue this command: route print. Post the output here, please.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcIez.jpg

Comment: Can I also see the output of *ipconfig*?

Comment: http://imgur.com/X7rTDMS